# faithful adjoint representation

Tags: lie-algebras, rt.representation-theory

When $n>3$ is even, how can I show that $PGL(n,\mathbb{R})$ has a faithful adjoint representation? Of course when n is even,  $PGL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is not connected.

Comment: Are you asking why $PGL_n(\mathbb{R})$ has trivial center?

Comment: NO. I know that for connected lie groups, if it has a trivial center then it has a faithful adjoint representation. Are you saying that the same statement holds for nonconnected lie groups? 

Comment: Ah, but ${\rm{PGL}}_n$ is connected for Zariski topology over any field. For a connected adjoint semisimple gp $G$ over a field $k$ then its adjoint representation has trivial kernel (so it's even a closed immersion).  For $k = \mathbf{R}$, the functor $G \rightsquigarrow G(\mathbf{R})$ from (perhaps disconnected) group varieties to Lie groups is clearly compatible with the formation of adjoint representations, so when $G$ is connected adjoint semisimple (connected for Zariski topology!) then $G(\mathbf{R})$ has faithful adjoint repn even if it is disconnected (for the classical topology). QED

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $A \in PGL_n(\mathbb{R})$ lies in the kernel of the adjoint representation.  Then for any lift $\tilde{A}$ of $A$ in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, and any traceless matrix $B$, we have $\tilde{A}B = B\tilde{A}$.  This implies $\tilde{A}$ is scalar, and hence $A$ is the identity.

Comment: How does $\tilde{A}B=B\tilde{A}$ imply $\tilde{A}$ is scalar?

Comment: The equation holds for all matrices $B$.  This implies $\tilde{A}$ is in the center of the matrix algebra.